# Can we guarantee the existence of such function?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am working on a research problem and I find my self with the following setting.

I have a function $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}, f = f(t)$ that is smooth everywhere except at $t = 0$. Can I find a smooth function $r(t)$ defined on $[0,1]$ such that 
$$\lim_{t\to 0^+}r(t)\max\{|f'(t)|,|f''(t)|\} =0,$$
$$\lim_{t\to 0^+}r'(t)|f'(t)| = - A,~A>0~?$$

I am wondering that perhaps this is possible since the conditions on $r$ are at first on the function and secondly on its first derivative, but $|f'(t)|$ appears on both conditions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If $f\equiv 0$ (with $f(0)=1$) then the second condition can't be satisfied.

Comment: @mfl how can $f\equiv 0$ be such that $f(0) = 1?$

Comment: I mean $f(0)=1, f(x)=0, \forall x\in (0,1]$.

Comment: @mfl, what if one assumes that $\lim_{t\to 0^+}|f'(t)| = \infty$?